# Android - Custom States with String value

Tags: android

I follow the tutorial at [this site](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/11/24/android-custom-states-for-state-list/) to implement custom state for state-list. It works with boolean attributes but doesn't with string attributes.

This is my source code:

- State-list:
- Attributes:

> ```
>     <declare-styleable name="CategoryIconView">
>             <attr name="category_id" format="string"/>
>         </declare-styleable>
> ```

- Custom View:

  ```
  public class CategoryIconView extends ImageView {

  // this is used when we want to merge our state with the ones from the system
  private static final int[] CATEGORY_ID_STATE_SET = {R.attr.category_id};

  String categoryID;
  public CategoryIconView(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }

  public CategoryIconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CategoryIconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
      LogUtils.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "category ID " + categoryID);
      final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
      if (categoryID != null) {
          mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CATEGORY_ID_STATE_SET);
      }
      return drawableState;
  }

  // this method will be used when you will need to set your image button state in the code
  public void setCategoryID(String categoryId){
      this.categoryID = "Three";
      refreshDrawableState();
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you just properly format the code?

Comment: Sorry. I dont know why i can not format the code with SO editor. Im using firefox.

Comment: Hello, I have given some answer, can you check that? After checking let me know.

Comment: Whether you tried with that solution?

Comment: Whether its working?

Comment: No Nigam. I think you don't understand my case. I am asking about using non-boolean attribute with selector, not about loading custom attribute from layout inside custom view. Please visit the site I linked on my question, It works like a charm with boolean but doesn't with other types.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Give me some time

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are missing some statements, below find the solution for this

```
public class CategoryIconView extends ImageView {

        // this is used when we want to merge our state with the ones from the system
        private static final int[] CATEGORY_ID_STATE_SET = {R.attr.category_id};

        String categoryID;

        public CategoryIconView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CategoryIconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
// R.styleable.CustomStates is the id of the custom state and CustomStates it's the name of your styleable
        // from attributes.xml
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CategoryIconView, 0, 0);

        // R.styleable.CustomStates_has_new_data is an ID that is created automatically when you create your
        // custom state list in attributes.xml
        categoryID = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.CategoryIconView_category_id);
        }

        public CategoryIconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            // R.styleable.CustomStates is the id of the custom state and CustomStates it's the name of your styleable
            // from attributes.xml
            TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CategoryIconView, 0, 0);

            // R.styleable.CustomStates_has_new_data is an ID that is created automatically when you create your
            // custom state list in attributes.xml
            categoryID = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.CategoryIconView_category_id);
        }

        @Override
        public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "category ID " + categoryID);
            final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
            if (categoryID != null) {
                mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CATEGORY_ID_STATE_SET);
            }
            return drawableState;
        }

        // this method will be used when you will need to set your image button state in the code
        public void setCategoryID(String categoryId) {
            this.categoryID = "Three";
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }
```